# Is it possible to render different React components on different screen sizes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, responsive-design, material-ui

I want to use different components that will render at different breakpoints. I tried to do it with Material-UI

```
import withWidth, { isWidthUp } from '@material-ui/core/withWidth';

function MyComponent(props) {
  if (isWidthUp('sm', props.width)) {
    return <NavBarMedium/>
           <HomePageMedium/>
  }

  return   <NavBarSmall/>
           <HomePageSmall/>
}

export default withWidth()(MyComponent);
```

and css

```
//Any component with className display-small will not be displayed above 600px 
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .display-small{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

and React-responsive

```
<MediaQuery query="(max-device-width: 600px)">
  <NavBarSmall/>
  <HomePageSmall/>
</MediaQuery>
```

But it seems they only work with normal html. Is there a way to make this work with react components or are there any other ways that this would work?

Answer (score 2):

```
function MyComponent(props) {
    let isMobile = useRef(false);
    const [mobile, setMobile] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const resize = () => {
            if(window.innerWidth > 600) {
                if(isMobile.current) {
                    isMobile.current = false;
                    setMobile(false);
                }
            } 
            else {
                if(!isMobile.current) {
                    isMobile.current = true;
                    setMobile(true)
                }
            }
         }

        window.addEventListener("resize",  resize);
        
        return () => window.removeListener("resize", resize);

    }, [])


    if (!isMobile.current) { /* or !mobile (state variable) */
      return (
          <> 
             <NavBarMedium />
             <HomePageMedium />
          </>
      )
    }
    else {
      return (
          <> 
             <NavBarSmall />
             <HomePageSmall />
          </>
      )
    }
}
```

Comment: this is far from perfect - it won't react to any change in device width (eg rotating a phone screen) while the app is running

Comment: I didn't know you would want resizing as well, for that I would need to implement state and a useRef hook

Comment: sorry, I'm not the OP, was just commenting that, as I saw it, this answer is incomplete. You're right that you need more complex techniques to implement that (although there are probably good third-party custom hooks for it).

Comment: I have added the resizing as well now.

Comment: I am using something similar for the time being, but as @RobinZigmond said, this code doesn't react to any changes and I wanted to know if there is a cleaner solution :)

EDIT: my bad, i didn't reload the page before commenting

Comment: I have edited the code with a solution for resizing.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that @FireFighter, I didnt reload the page before commenting. Thank you, i owe u a beer.

Comment: isMobile.current(false) needs to be isMobile.current = false @FireFighter

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Material ui media query hooks

https://material-ui.com/es/components/use-media-query/

next code show how i use:

```
export default function MainWraper() {

  // 0px  xs   600px  sm  960px lg   1280px xl  1920px
  const phone =  useMediaQuery("(max-width: 460px)");
  const tablet =  useMediaQuery("(min-width: 451px) and (max-width: 960px)");
  const desktop =  useMediaQuery("(min-width: 961px)");


  if(phone) return (<phonewrapper/>);
  if(tablet) return (<tabletwrapper/>);
  if(desktop) return (<desktoprapper/>);


}
```

Comment: How would this work exactly? I don't really understand what u mean by `<phonewrapper/>` sadly.

Comment: For example an app have common components like the navbar, product search, product list, product details. In the phonewrapper you arrange all in vertical layout, In tablet divide in rows, navbar in firts row, search in second, the third row will have product list and product details to the left. For desktop will be navbar on top and three columns with : search list and details.